# Max parallel AJAX requests using Laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, session

I'm developing an application that needs make more than 20 parallel requests via AJAX to the server.
In order to do that, I've changed the hostname on the request because this app reaches the maximum number of concurrent requests. I changed the domain name as follows:

```
www1.domain.com
www2.domain.com
www3.domain.com
www4.domain.com
www1.domain.com
....
www4.domain.com
```

I'm using the following code to do the AJAX call:

```js
var parallel_uri = el.protocol + "//" + host + parallel + '.domain.com' + el.pathname;
return jQuery.ajax({
    url: parallel_uri + '/' + id + '/' + 'status',
    type: 'GET',
    async: true
});
```

But when I do that, I saw that I lose my session and I get redirected to login page.
The `SESSION_DOMAIN constant in Laravel is declared like this:

```php
SESSION_DOMAIN = .domain.com
```

And I enabled CORS, following reading of this [link on Gist](https://gist.github.com/technoknol/1a35ca4b150215f491d5c807940bd4ef)

How am I able to stop the error for maximum concurrent requests?

Comment: Keep in mind that Laravel does not support fully concurrent access to the same session. Reads work, but writes may be lost. This has been the case since at least Laravel 4.2. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/14385

Comment: Hi @sisve I'm using redis driver to handle sessions for this reason I wouldn't have the problem of concurrent writes.

Comment: "needs make more than 20 parallel requests via AJAX to the server.". I would question the design methodology in that case. What's the reason for this? Obviously I don't know the requirements but would something like websockets provide a better solution? Or loading more content up-front?

Comment: @BernatMut _all_ session implementations in Laravel has this problem. Don't confuse it with file locking issues, it's much larger than that. The session content is read at the start of the request, and written at the end, and any modifications done the session during this time by another request is lost.

Comment: @ADyson Yes websockets could be a better solution in other scenarios I have a mixed solution, but at this moment I can't deploy this solution on the platform. I'm working on a legacy design and I cannot change it, I can't install a websocket server.

Comment: @sisve, ah I get confused about that, thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score -1):

After some tries, I found a solution I had to use token auth with this kind of auth I was able to make this kind of requests.